# NSTableView drag & drop item to a new position

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4.2

How do I start implementing the drag & drop capability in an NSTableView to re-order items like the one we see in OSX's `Language & Text` preferences panel?

I can't find any references online. Maybe I am looking for it with the wrong keywords?

Maybe it is not even NSTableView, maybe I need to extend NSTableColumn or NSCell.

I am using XCode 4.2 in Snow Leopard.

Any help appreciated!

*I attach an image from the mentioned panel to give an idea (dragging item "Deutsch" to the last position):*

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947091/implementing-drag-and-drop-in-nstableview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420671/how-to-handle-nstableview-drag-and-drop-for-multiple-rows

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You are not making a sufficient effort.  Ask Google or whatever about "NSTableView drag move."

Comment: @ElTomato did you know that googling "NSTableView drag move" gives this page as the 2nd result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the following below method for drag and drop

```
1) - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRows:(NSArray*)rows toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard

2) - (NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination

3) - (void)draggedImage:(NSImage *)anImage endedAt:(NSPoint)aPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation

4) -(void)awakeFromNib
{
        [tableView registerForDraggedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeString, nil]];
        [tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];
}
```

Also in bindings connect your table to datasource of your fileowner